# Shell Script para mostrar listado por terminal linux

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, shell-script

Necesito mediante un fichero que me han proporcionado llamado "grupos.txt" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mostrar por terminal lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con estas condiciones:

- No puedes usar el comando "wc".
- El nombre del fichero debe pedirse al usuario.
- Si el usuario introduce un nombre de un fichero que no existe, debe mostrar un mensaje de error y volver a pedir el nombre al usuario.
- El Script debe funcionar bien con cualquier fichero que introduzca el usuario y que tenga el formato indicado.
- Si hay más de un grupo con el mismo número máximo de usuarios, se debe mostrar
  el nombre de todos ellos.

Hasta el momento lo más cerca que estoy de mostrarlo es esto:

```
clear read -p "Introduce el nombre del archivo: " nombre
if [ ! -f $nombre ];then
echo "incorrecto"
else
echo "En el fichero proporcionado tenemos 4 grupos:"
for i in $(cat grupos.txt | awk '{print NF}')
do
for cabecera in $(cat grupos.txt | awk '{print 1}' | head -$i | tail -1)
do
echo "$cabecera $i usuarios"
done
done
fi
```

Comment: Hola. No me queda claro como necesitas que se muestre, ¿podrías, por favor, indicarlo?

Comment: Hola Adrián, debería de mostrarse asi:
https://pix.my/ae7fQp

Comment: El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. Las preguntas que sólo muestran imagenes terminan cerradas. Saludos

Comment: Perdona, ya está puesto el código.

Answer (score 0):

Esto tiene pinta de tarea. Intenta desarrollar tu pensamiento lógico y tu habilidad para encontrar cosas en Google. Pedir que te hagan la tarea no te enseña mucho.

Sin embargo, voy a tratar de mostrarte tus errores y una forma de resolverlo (recuerda que en programación siempre hay miles de formas de resolver la misma cosa).

---

Hay varias cosas que corregir en tu código:

1. `clear read` son dos comandos distintos. Puedes utilizar `clear && read` o separarlo en dos líneas como he hecho, pero uno seguido del otro no se va a ejecutar. Pruébalo. El ensayo y error es la mejor forma de aprender a mi parecer.
2. Si estás escribiendo en bash, se considera mejor práctica usar corchetes dobles `[[`. Más info [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-double-square-brackets-preferable-over-single-square-brackets-in-ba)
3. Estás escribiendo "tenemos 4 grupos", lo cual carece de programación alguna. Y sí la lista tiene 3 grupos? Y sí tiene 200 grupos?
4. Te piden que "*Si el usuario introduce un nombre de un fichero que no existe, debe mostrar un mensaje de error y volver a pedir el nombre al usuario*". En tu código solo estás mostrando un mensaje de error. Te ha faltado volver a pedir el nombre.
5. No entiendo tus dos bucles `for` anidados. Me explicas qué querías lograr?
6. igual que en el punto 3., Si estás guardando el nombre del fichero en una variables, no escribas `grupos.txt`.

---

Dicho esto, este código haría lo que pides (salvo la parte de "*Si hay más de un grupo con el mismo número máximo de usuarios, se debe mostrar el nombre de todos ellos*". No sé cuál es el máximo de usuarios):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
while true; do
        read -p "Introduce el nombre del archivo: " fichero

        if [[ ! -f $fichero ]]; then
                echo "No existe el fichero $fichero"
        else
                break
        fi
done

count="$(cat $fichero | grep -Ec ':')"

echo "En el fichero proporcionado tenemos $count grupos:"

while read linea; do
        grupo="$(echo $linea | cut -d ':' -f 1)"
        nombres="$(echo $linea | cut -d ':' -f 2)"

        count="$(echo $nombres | awk '{print NF}')"

        echo "${grupo}: ${count} usuarios"

done < $fichero
```